# What is "Signature Verification Failed" in Solana?

Tags: javascript, solana

I'm trying to call a Solana Program, and when I run `sendAndConfirmTransaction`, it gives me `Signature Verification Failed`, and I'm not sure why.

```js
const {sendAndConfirmTransaction, clusterApiUrl, Connection} = require("@solana/web3.js");

let signer = Keypair.generate();
let anotherKeypair = Keypair.generate();

let transaction = someInstruction(signer, anotherKeypair); 
let connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('testnet'));

sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [signer]
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Solana, you need to pass in *both* the keypairs of the signer, *and* the keypairs of the accounts you're creating.

```
const {sendAndConfirmTransaction, clusterApiUrl, Connection} = require("@solana/web3.js");

let signer = Keypair.generate();
let anotherKeypair = Keypair.generate();

let transaction = someInstruction(signer, anotherKeypair); 
let connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('testnet'));

sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [signer, anotherKeypair] // <-- If you made the keypair, you probably want it here!
);
```

If you're using a wallet connect library, like `@solana/wallet-adapter-react`, you don't have the `signer`, but you will still have any keypairs of accounts your generating:

```js
const { sendTransaction } = useWallet();

const anotherKeypair = Keypair.generate(); 

const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
  signers: [anotherKeypair] // You probably want to pass in the keypair here!
});
```

Comment: I give a +1 to this sentence: `In Solana, you need to pass in both the keypairs of the signer, and the keypairs of the accounts you're creating`

Comment: This answer did not work for me, I posted the version that worked for me using paritalSign

Comment: How would you partially sign a program rpc call i.e.
`await program.methods.someMethod({...}).accounts({...}).signers(signers).rpc()`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

**tx.partialSign**

```
let tx = new Transaction();
const anotherKeypair = Keypair.generate(); 

tx.recentBlockhash =  (await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized")).blockhash;
tx.feePayer = new PublicKey(publicKeyStringfromWallet);
console.log(tx)

tx.partialSign(anotherKeypair) // THIS SIGNS for web3 keypair

const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(tx); //THIS signs wallet keypair
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `isSigner` key, if `isSigner: true`, you need to provide the signer.

For example, the following code will not work because we mention payerAta (Associated Token Account of Payer) has `isSigner:true`.

```js
const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [
      {
        pubkey: programAta.address,
        isSigner: false,
        isWritable: true,
      },
      {
        pubkey: payerAta.address,
        isSigner: true,
        isWritable: true,
      },
    ],
    programId,
    data: Buffer.alloc(0), // All instructions are hellos
  });
  await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    new Transaction().add(instruction),
    [payer]
  );
}
```

In this case either we change `payerAta` to `payer`, or change the `isSigner` to `false`